# how to redirect http to https in nginx, my default port is 81 on nginx

Tags: http, nginx, https

> I am trying to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. My default port is 81 on nginx.

```
server {
    listen 81;
    server_name deveshvyas.in;
    return 307 https: //deveshvyas.in$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen[::]: 443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    #
    ssl_code
    server_name deveshvyas.in;
    ssl_certificate / etc / nginx / ssl / nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key / etc / nginx / ssl / nginx.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http: //127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

> https is working fine but fails in redirection

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to `www.deveshvyas.in` or `deveshvyas.in`? There is a mismatch between the `return 307` in the first `server` block and the `server_name` in the second `server` block.

Comment: Thank u Richard, I have updated the configuration but still, it does not work.

Comment: The configuration looks fine (other than the extra spaces and the non-standard port). Did you restart `nginx` and **clear the browser cache** before retesting?